# htaccess rewrite with Wordpress for translating url slug but don't show in browser bar

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have urls which include slugs that should be displayed in englich.
but the cms cannot interprete them right but can the german ones.

- `blah.com/en/team/sprache/french` works but is not pretty
- `blah.com/en/team/language/french` does not work, but should be in the browser address bar and is quite pretty.

I tried this `.htaccess` but it does not work - I land on a 404.
can anybody explain what goes wrong here:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# special rules for english urls
RewriteRule ^(.*)/language/(.*)$ $1/sprachen/$2

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

you need to know that the slugs can occure more then once in the url and there are some other slugs that must be translated as well.

Comment: @anubhava tried that out. didn't work.
I don't land on that page. I get a 404.

What does that config do ... why is the rule somehow ignored

Comment: to the -1er: please provide comment why.

Comment: Ah it is `WordPress`. No internal rewrite rules won't work. You will need to use WP rewrite API in your theme

Comment: @anubhava is there a best-practice for that? any link to a good explanation? Found that so far: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API (which is an overview only), you could provide it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal rewrite rules don't work with `wordpress` as `WP` uses `index.php` as default front controller for all the URLs.

- You can use `permalinks` to customize how your URLs will appear to your clients.
- For advanced URL customization use [WP rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) to write your rewrite rules in PHP inside your theme. [Here is a tutorial on WP rewrite rule APIs](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474).